# Bash script program with Qt UI

Tags: bash, qt, user-interface, arguments

How can I pass the argument from the bash script in Qt?
For example with the script

```
echo "Enter keywords: "
read test1
result1=$(find . -name "*$test1*" -print0)
echo $result1
```

I want to let the user type keyword to lineEdit in Qt and when they press button the result of `find . -name "*$test1*" -print0` will be shown

Comment: You could use `QProcess` for executing and reading back the results of the find command. Better would be to just search within `QDir` and omit the bash totally if you want to use Qt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`QProcess`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) class is designed to start other processes and allows you to interact with the result.

To start it, see the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#running-a-process)

Be aware that this is asynchronous, so you will either need to play with the signal/slot or block, using `QProcess::waitForFinished`.

The result, you can then get from `QProcess::readAllStandardOutput()` or `QProcess::readAllStandardError()` and export to a widget for showing.